# Deploy new/ updated application version to Azure Batch Services via RESTful API?

Tags: rest, azure, azure-batch

I'm building a console app that is designed to scale in an Azure Batch Service, but I can't seem to figure out how I can update the batch service application programmatically.

I've been looking at the API reference at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/batchmanagement/ which has options to create, update, and modify applications for the batch service... but I don't see how to actually push the new binaries to the batch service, or how to tell the batch service the blob location of the new binaries.  Am I missing something obvious?

Comment: Maybe you can copy the new binaries to the batch nodes and then use the task to update the application.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cool, I think you should add more information for the specific design scenario you have. I have added the API and have also detailed few things which might help in better understanding and also sorry if I missed anything obvious `:)`.

Down below, as an example I came out with one possible scenario and answered it as thinking out loud process.

WRT (With respect to) the question:

- How are your new binaries generated? and Do you manage them on the fly?
- `create, update` etc: please refer to the following doc which talks about the `create, delete, or update` : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/batchmanagement/application
- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/batchmanagement/pool/update
- some sample reference for update \ create: https://github.com/Azure-Samples/azure-batch-samples/blob/master/CSharp/AccountManagement/Program.cs#L241
- Most of the samples reside here for idea sake : https://github.com/Azure-Samples/azure-batch-samples/tree/master/CSharp

Coming back to the more information part: (Reason I ask is to get clarity for the design how app is trying to utilize resources etc...) a really good over all intake on resource management et. al. here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/batch/batch-api-basics .

More information which should be though for scaling reasons are like:

- Your application creates pool with certain amount of resource or packages at pool level or task level?
- How are you managing your resources?
- What scenario will require a binary update: i.e. will it be in the middle of the task getting run or something else?

**Sample Scenario which comes to my mind**

Say for example:

> My pool is running 20 tasks, `task 1` generates the binary which will
>   get used in `task 4` then 2 concepts comes to my mind first : my tasks
>   are dependent tasks so look for [this concept](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/batch/batch-task-dependencies), then I can do
>   upload files form my tasks using output [file concept here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/batch/batch-task-output-files), then I
>   use the new uploaded files in my task now.

Hope this helps. Thanks!

Comment: I'm trying to map out the process in code, but ultimately that's so I can get it going in Azure DevOps.  I should state for the record that this is a POC that I'm working on to parallelize a fairly long-running and complicated set of tasks, so I am by no means an expert in any of the batch-related technologies.

Comment: @JeremyHolovacs cool, yeah, `batch` is extremely robust and easy once you sink in the concepts, I have added few helpful links and the `sample` code should help, if you have anything specific in the scenario you have then feel free to comment and I can try and give my opinion. but do read through what I mentioned above and once basics are sink in and look for concepts like `Task dependency, or Outputfiles` for resource management, `Resource files or application package` can be good place to start. feel free to ping with more info. `:)`